# The style of the title of a book @incollection shown in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I use `\usepackage{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` for producing the bibliography in my book. Here is a sample for the items @collection built in my lib.bib file:

```
@incollection{MABh,
    Booktitle = {The Tibetan Tripitaka - Peking edition},
    Date-Added = {2016-10-01 20:30:51 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-11-15 13:34:00 +0000},
    Editor = {Suzuki, Daisetz T.},
    Key = {MABh},
    Pages = {for Peking 264b8-408b7 (p.108-166) And for Derge 220b1-348a7},
    Publisher = {Tokyo : Suzuki Research Foundation, 1962},
    Title = {Candrak{\=\i}rti's Dbu Ma La 'Jug Pa'i Bshad Ba Shes Bya Ba (Tibetan translation of Madhyamak{\=a}vat{\=a}rabh{\=a}{\d s}ya)},
    url = "https://www.tbrc.org/#library_work_ViewByOutline-O1GS60111GS36115%7CW23703",
    Volume = {for Peking (Q 5263) dbu ma, 'a (vol.98) and for Derge (D 3862) dbu ma, 'a},
    Year = {1962}}
```

However, when this item is printed in the bibliography, it shows as follows:
[image]

AS you see, the real book name is not printed in every first letter capital style. Please tell me how can I get such book name just as what I write in the "title". Thanks.

Comment: Off-topic: For entries of type `@incollection`, one should provide an `author` field.

Comment: @Mico I don't write Auther on purpose because I don't want it printed in my Biblio. According to an academic custom in our field, we need to print the identifying key (MABh for this case), but I don't know how to change the "author-year" system in Bibtex if I lay down the author's name there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apalike` bibliography style practices "sentence style" for the contents of the `title` field. If you don't want to allow this and, instead, wish to preserve the existing capitalization patterns, simply encase the contents of the `title` field in an extra pair of curly braces:

```
Title = {{Candrak{\=\i}rti's Dbu Ma La 'Jug Pa'i Bshad Ba Shes Bya Ba 
          (Tibetan translation of Madhyamak{\=a}vat{\=a}rabh{\=a}{\d s}ya)}},
```